# How can I know an annotation that is annotated with another

Tags: java, annotations

like this

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Component {
    String value() default "";
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Configuration {
   String value() default "";
}
```

How can I konw Configuration is annotated Component?
And what's the relationship between `@Interface` and the interface `Annotation`.
I have a Object annotated @Configuration , `obj.getClass().getAnnotation(Configuration.class).getClass()==Configu‌​ration.class` it's false

Answer (score 1):

Checking whether an annotation is present is rather easy, any `Class` has an `isAnnotationPresent(clazz)`-method allowing you to check whether an annotation of a specific type is present.

You can only check if an annotation is present when it has a retention policy 'RUNTIME', for otherwise the annotations are stripped by either the compiler or the JVM.

I've created a little sample for you: http://ideone.com/CrXGVc

Comment: but if i have a class annotated `@Component` , `class.getAnnotation(Configuration.class).getClass()==Configuration.class` it's false. so `clazz.getAnnotations()`,`annotation.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Configuration.class)` not work